# Firebase function works as expected in emulator but not in production

Tags: node.js, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

Edited: Added the full function

---

I have a firebase function that retrieves the content of a URL as RSS, here is the relevant part of the function:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {onSchedule} from "firebase-functions/v2/scheduler";
import axios from 'axios';

export const getKittens = onSchedule("0 * * * *", async (event) => {
    const responseBody = (await axios("https://news.google.com/rss/search?hl=he&gl=IL&ceid=IL%3Ahe&oc=11&q=kittens")).data;
    admin.firestore().collection("news").doc("latest").set({response: responseBody});
});
```

When I run this function in my local emulator, I get a proper RSS response as expected. When running in production, the request does not return any values, and instead fails with error 503. Log Enclosed. What might be the problem, and how do I solve it? I have tried this with node https request, node-fetch, and axios, and also added User-Agent headers with the same results

---

Relevant portion of the log:

```
ERROR 2023-10-19T21:00:14.341994Z AxiosError: Request failed with status code 503 at settle (/workspace/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:1913:12) at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/workspace/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:2995:11) at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:529:35) at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:552:15) at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1368:12) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  {
    "textPayload": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 503\n    at settle (/workspace/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:1913:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/workspace/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:2995:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:529:35)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:552:15)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1368:12)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {",
    "insertId": "653198de000537eaf5715d09",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "configuration_name": "aggregator",
        "project_id": "**************",
        "location": "us-central1",
        "service_name": "aggregator",
        "revision_name": "aggregator-00009-pox"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-10-19T21:00:14.341994Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "instanceId": "0037d6d5d3aabb0489035542a4a56814f64b475a66a0abd00193b52b487c163d72e73e1accb41fa3e805d52ffa0bb9fd3c0a58ae6ea199ec89a4d8b32203c5b285",
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions"
    },
    "logName": "projects/************/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-10-19T21:00:14.477253017Z",
    "errorGroups": [
      {
        "id": "CNGCx7HHwp2GvQE"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Is there an error code or other information?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire function (not just two lines) and explain how you invoke it.  Include all logs. We should be able to duplicate the results using the instructions you provide.

Comment: @Phix - The error code is 503, I added the log entry

Comment: @DougStevenson - Added the full function and the log as you requested